# finding a word from a file and substitution into other file

Tags: c++, substitution

I have two text files like these:
11.txt:

```
1 5.66
2 4.95
3 2.55
4 0.99
5 2.87
```

NB.txt:

```
1 2 3 4 5
4 5 3 2 1
3 4 5 1 2
```

I have written the below code to fine, for example, "1" from File 1, and search it in File 2, then substitute "1" with "5.66". and repeat it for other numbers, i.e. 2,3,4,5. but I don't know why it doesn't work. additionally, it doesn't read the first line of 11.txt.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    string  line;
    double AtomId, Atom_radius,search ;

    ifstream AtomId_file ("11.txt");
    string namefile;
    if (AtomId_file.is_open()){
        for (int linenox = 0; getline (AtomId_file,line) && linenox < 6; linenox++){
            if (linenox == 0)  AtomId_file>>AtomId>>Atom_radius;
            }
        cout<<"AtomId: "<<AtomId<<" Atom_radius: "<<Atom_radius<<endl;
        cout<<namefile<<"\n";

    }

    ifstream NB("NB.txt");

    size_t pos;
    if (NB.is_open())
      {     
          search = AtomId;
          getline(NB,line); 
          pos=line.find(search);
          if(pos!=string::npos) 
            {
                search = Atom_radius;
                cout <<"Found!";
            }
      } 

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("12.txt");
    myfile << search << "\n";
}
```

the output in 12.txt is:

```
2
```

instead of :

```
5.66 4.95 2.55 0.99 2.87
0.99 2.87 2.55 4.95 5.66
2.55 0.99 2.87 5.66 4.95
```

Comment: Why don't you store the data from those files into appropriate data structures like a `std::map` and/or array?  Then work with those structures to produce the output.

Comment: Dear @PaulMcKenzie thanks for attention. I am so novice in programming, then I dont know how I should use `std::map` or something like this.

Comment: Then just do the first part of the assignment.  You failed to read in 11.txt into something you can use.  Instead, you wrote code to read in one number, and then when you overwrite that one number when you read in the second number, then you read in the third number overwriting the second, etc.  That's the main issue you need to figure out -- how to store *all* the data first.  You don't do that by declaring a single variable -- you need an array, a map, or some other container and for each number pair read in, store it in the array or map.

Comment: Just a few hints: Take the [tour] and read [ask]. Extract a [mcve]. Further, learn how to use a debugger, it allows you to step through your program and inspect the variable state at every point, so you can determine the exact place where things go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your are new to C++.

I analyzed your code and put in tons of comments, where the errors are. You need to change your design. Before starting to type in code, you must first write down, **what** should be done. Then, and this is most important, you think (without taking any language into consideration) **how** you can solve the problem. This is most important. Also for you later programming career. The **design** is most important. So think 3 hours, how it could be done. Search possible design solutions in the internet. Write it on a piece of paper or somewhere.

Then, after hours of thinking, select an apropriate language and check, how it could be implemented.

I show a standard C++ solution below. You will not understand it immediately. So please try to understand the **design** first. Then lookup all used **C++-statements** in the internet and try to understand.

Read some good C++ books, before starting to code.

Please see first your commented code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;    // You should not use this line at all. Use qualified names.

int main()
{
    string  line;
    double AtomId, Atom_radius, search;  // These variables are not initalized

    ifstream AtomId_file("r:\\11.txt");
    string namefile;
    if (AtomId_file.is_open()) {   // You should not use is_open but simply   if (AtomId_file)

        // Here you have a loop running from 0,1,2,3,4,5. That are 6 loops. But you have only 5 lines in your sourcefile
        // The you read one line, each time the loops runs. So in the beginning, this will read the first line
        for (int linenox = 0; getline(AtomId_file, line) && linenox < 6; linenox++) {
            // And only for the first loop event, when linenox==0, you read then next line "2 4.95"
            // So you read already lines. But not more.
            // ypu need to read line by line (only one per loop) and then store the result in an appropriate STL Container
            if (linenox == 0)  AtomId_file >> AtomId >> Atom_radius;
        }

        // Since you assigned the data only once, the values will be 2, 4.95
        // They will never change
        cout << "AtomId: " << AtomId << " Atom_radius: " << Atom_radius << endl;
        // The variable namefile has never been initailized and is always emtpy, So ""
        cout << namefile << "\n";

    }

    ifstream NB("r:\\NB.txt");

    size_t pos;  // Not initialized
    if (NB.is_open())  // Not recommended. Use "if (NB) instead". In general, use more meaningful variable names
    {
        search = AtomId;   // search is now 2 and never somthing else
        getline(NB, line); // Read exactly one (and only this one time) a line containing 1,  5.66
        pos = line.find(search);  // So, 2 will never be found
        if (pos != string::npos)   // Always false, can never be true
        {
            search = Atom_radius;   // Will never be executed
            cout << "Found!";       // Will never be executed
        }
    }

    ofstream myfile;  // You can write directly  ofstream myfile("12.txt");
    myfile.open("12.txt"); 
    myfile << search << "\n";  // And the output will always be 2.
}
```

And here is a correct and working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() {

    // Open the file 11.txt and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream file11("11.txt"); file11) {

        // Define variable id and attribute and initialize them to theire default values.
        unsigned int id{};
        double attribute{};

        // Here we will store all values (id, attribute) of all lines that we read in the follwing loop
        std::unordered_map<unsigned, double> replacement{};

        // Read in a llop ALL lines and extract id and attribute, and, check if this worked
        while (file11 >> id >> attribute) {
            // Create a new replacement value for id
            replacement[id] = attribute;
        }
        // So, now, all data from file 11.txt is read and stored.
        // We will now read the next file and store the data

        // Open next input file NB.txt and check, if that worked
        if (std::ifstream fileNB("NB.txt"); fileNB) {

            // And already now, open output file 12.txt and check, if open worked
            if (std::ofstream myfile("12.txt"); myfile) {

                // Read a complete line and check, if that worked. Read all lines in a loop
                for (std::string line; std::getline(fileNB, line); ) {

                    // Put the line in a std::istringstream, so that we can extract each single value
                    std::istringstream iss(line);

                    // We will store the single values of the just read line into a vector
                    // This we do, because we do not know, how many values will be in that line
                    // We use a so called iterator, to iterate over all elements in the just read line
                    // The result will be stored in a vector
                    // The istream_iterator will call the ">>"-operator, until the line is empty
                    // For the vector, we use its range constructor
                    std::vector values(std::istream_iterator<unsigned>(iss), {});

                    // Now go through all values, replace them and out the result into the output file
                    for (const unsigned& u : values)    myfile << replacement[u] << " ";
                    myfile << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course there are many other possible solutions

Comment: Dear Armin Montigny, so many thanks for your kindness, when I changed `std::vector` (on line 47) into `std::vector<double>`, it worked, thank you for wonderful comments, too